# Symfony4: Doctrine OneToMany relationship in a form throws error 'Could not determine access type for property "X" in class "Y"'

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, symfony4, criteria

I have a parent form with many collection but i want to limit the number of the collection so I created criteria to limit the number of result to 8
this works fine for the display but not while editing

I get the following error:

> "Could not determine access type for property "Collections" in class
>   "App\Entity\Parent": Neither the property "Collections" nor one of the
>   methods "addCollections()"/"removeCollections()", "setCollections()",
>   "Collections()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access
>   in class "App\Entity\Parent"."

That's probably because `$this->Collections->matching($criteria)` returns an `ArrayCollection` in stead of the default `PersistentCollection`.

I have no clue how to proceed from here.

Could someone give me some suggestions and references?

```php
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Collection", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
* @ORM\OrderBy({"createdOn" = "DESC"})
*/
private $Collections;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->Collection; = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getCollections(): Collection
{
   $criteria = Criteria::create()
       ->setMaxResults(8);
   return $this->Collections->matching($criteria);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this exception because the property `$collections` is `private` (not `public`) and there's no setter-method for it, too.

This way the form component can not set the value for `$collections` from the outside.

Add a `setCollections` method as follows:

```
/** @var Collection */
private $collections;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->collections = new ArrayCollection();
 }

public function setCollections(?Collection $collections)
{
    foreach ($collections as $collection) {
        $collection->setParent($this);
    }
    $this->collections = $collections;
}
```

Then set the option `'by_reference' => false` in your form-type for the `collections` field.

You probably want to rename your `Collection` entity to something more meaningful like `Car` or `Picture` and use `$cars` or `$pictures`, too. :)

Further double-check the property-names for and upper and lowercase mismatches!

- `protected $collections` -> lowercase
- in the `__construct` method: collection**s** -> lowercase, add "s" at the end.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolai-Fröhlich for your help, now I got this  "Attempted to call an undefined method named "addParent" of class "App\Entity\Collection".

Comment: Should be `setParent` as it's a `OneToMany` relation. If the method doesn't exist -> create it. The `Many` side needs to know what their parent is to store the `parent_id`.